# How to acces is_* property in laravel model?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am working with laravel 4.2 and have table in db with property `is_active`.
When I try to access this model property:
`$model->is_active`
I am getting following error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

So question is how to access this property?
Please do not recommend to rename this field in the database if possible because this is already existing database in production.

Here is my model class:

```
class Position extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = "hr_positions";

    protected $fillable = ['slug', 'info_small', 'info_full', 'is_active', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'tags', 'user_create_id', 'user_update_id'];

    use \MyApp\Core\StartEndDateTrait;

    public function postulations(){
        return $this->hasMany('Postulation', 'position_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Latest notice:

All this error ocurrs on a page where I am creating my entity. In the controller before forwarding to the page I am doing:
`$position = new \Position();`

and then, for example, following code produce error as well:
`dd(($position->getAttribute('is_active')));`

but if I replace `$position = new \Position();` with

```
$position = \Position::first();
```

error is gone?

What is going on here?????

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does a lot of magic behind the scenes, as in, calls a lot of [php magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

If a called property is not defined, __call is invoked which in Eloquent calls getAttribute().
Steps taken by `getAttribute($key)` are

1. Is there a database field by this key? If so, return it.
2. Is there a loaded relationship by this key? If so, return it.
3. Is there a camelCase method of this key? If so, return it. *(is_active looks for isActive method)*
4. Returns null.

The only time that exception is thrown is in **step 3.**

When you create a new instance, eloquent has no idea what kind of fields it has, so if you have a method by the same name, it will always throw a relation error, this seems to be the case in both Laravel4 and Laravel5.

**How to avoid it?** Use the `getAttributeValue($key)` method. It has no relation checks and returns *null* by default.

Alternatively you can also add a [get mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for your field.

Comment: I have tried byt again error: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: @gandra404 Do you have a method `isActive()` in`Position` class?

Comment: here are some facts:   
- I do not have method `isActive()` in `Position `class
- I have database field `is_active`: https://i.imgur.com/IkriM6C.png

Comment: Seems that problem has to do with `Position` instance. If instance is retrieved from DB that it works. But if created `$p = new \Position();` then error is thrown when accessing field.

Comment: @gandra404 I expanded my answer. This seems like an edgecase bug in Laravel4 and Laravel5.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack for this. Still not ideal but at least I have some solution. Better any than none.

So This code produce problem:

```
$position = new \Position();
if($position->is_active){
    //
}
```

and this one works fine, this is solution even hacky but solution:

```
$position = new \Position(['is_active' => 0]);
if($position->is_active){
    //
}
```

I will wait if someone give better, cleaner solution. If no one comes in next few days I will accept mine.